# Blacklisted Links on Facebook Removed

Tags: hyperlink, facebook-javascript-sdk, malware

My website had malware on it, so FB blacklisted it and redirects links to my website to google.  But now my site is  clean (checked on google webmaster tools and Sucuri but my links still don't work.  How do I get whitelisted, or at least un-blacklisted?

Answer (score 0):

Try waiting for some days. Once Google is confirm of no malicious activity on your website, they will clear it.